# Getter function vs duplicated value in terms of memory usage?

Tags: go

For example I have an array of Item:

```golang
// approach 1: Getter function
type Item[T any] struct {
  data T,
  getPriority func(item Item[T]) int // get priority from data
}

// approach 2: Duplicate data
type Item2[T any] struct {
  data T,
  priority int, // get priority from data
}

a := []*Item[int] { ... }
a2 := []*Item2[int] { ... }
```

if a have 1M items like this:

```golang
getPriority := func(item Item[int]) int {
  return item.data
}
for i:=1; i<1e6; i++ {
  a = append(a, Item[int]{i, getPriority })
  a2 = append(a2, Item2[int]{i, i })
}
```

which `Item` or `Item2` is better in terms of memory?
how Golang stores the function in Item.getPriority, Do those all point to the same memory address?

---

NOTE: Due to some abstraction reason, I cannot use struct method:

```golang
func (r Item[T]) getPriority()  {}
```

Comment: 1. The name of the language is Go. 2. "how [does Go] stores the function in Item.getPriority [...]?" This is unspecified by the language. It's safe to assume that most current implementations just store some kind function pointer. 3. Which one is better depends solely on facts and criteria you did not  mention. 4. Stop guessing (or asking) and start benchmarking. Performance and memory usage might be pretty different. 5. Your pseudocode makes no real sense as priority is never used so "the best" solution would be to use just a single int.

Answer (score 1):

For memory usage:

- `getPriority func(item Item[T]) int` is a function, was stored as a pointer refer to the function in above code => pointer take 4/8 bytes on 32/64bit system
- `priority int` is a int, => int take 4/8 bytes on 32/64bit system

So in terms of memory, both above approaches are equal.

On the other side, should use function approach as it uses `item.data` as the single source of truth.